# Uninstallation issues in python numpy

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I am in the process of downgrading numpy1.13 to 1.7. In order to do this, I am uninstalling the latest version so that i can install with a older version,

I have uninstalled numpy in anaconda python using

```
`pip uninstall numpy`
```

After uninstalling, when i see the `conda list`, numpy is still listed in the library list.

When i tried again with `pip uninstall numpy`, its throwing me an errors as `"`cannot uninstall requirement numpy, not installed".`

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thank you .

Comment: Anaconda is using it's own virtual environment I think. Try outside anaconda.

Comment: try `python -m numpy` should give you `python: No module named numpy`

Answer (score 4):

try this if you are using anaconda:

```
conda uninstall numpy
conda install numpy=1.7
```

or this if you are using python pip:

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy==1.7
```

Comment: just use conda install numpy='downgradedversion' it will just downgrade the version. If you uninstall first, it will remove other related packages. that can cause problems as it was in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The following commands works for me to uninstall

```
pip3 uninstall numpy
pip uninstall numpy
```

Then, for installing

```
pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda is a package manager for python, you can install in anaconda environment either by `conda` or by `pip`. Uninstalling a package depends on how you installed the package.

When you run the `conda list` command yo get output like below

```
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda3\envs\base:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
astroid                   2.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
ca-certificates           2020.6.20            hecda079_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2020.6.20        py36h9f0ad1d_0    
colorama                  0.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
django                    2.2                      py36_0
djangorestframework       3.11.0                     py_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.8.0                    15_mkl    conda-forge
numpy                     1.18.4           py36h4d86e3b_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1g               he774522_0    conda-forge
```

you can check the channel from which you have installed the dependency. If you installed a package via `conda` it is safe to uninstall using `conda` only